# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject

Tags: java, maven

I am creating a project with maven, I use the ibm Json package, when compiling I don't get any errors, however when I run it I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/json/java/JSONObject
at myp.Peticion.llamaServidor(Peticion.java:44)
at myp.Peticion.daFormatoCsv(Peticion.java:59)
at myp.Proyecto01.main(Proyecto01.java:75)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 3 more
```

I understand that it finds the class at compile time but not at run time, I add the dependencies part of the pom

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api</groupId>
          <artifactId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.json</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.11</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Could someone help me with solving this problem?

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: First: `mvn install` then `java -jar target/project1.jar`

Comment: You need to put your dependencies on your classpath. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven